# Why would IE7 ask my approval( the user) when there is a window.prompt?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, prompt

I have in my code a window.prompt, which should stop the flow of the code until user put in some value.
Of course IE7 try to protect me from myself and instead of showing the prompt it shows the security tab (top of the page where it alerts to the users that a script wants to open a window).
What is even worse is that the prompt is ignore and the rest of the flow is being done. Regardless to say this can't work as the script is missing data from the user.

What should I do to avoid that security bar, as this script is part of the page/domain.

Comment: clever new tag...I predict it will become popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.prompt()` is no longer usable on the general web for this very reason, since there's no way to get round the security banner in your script. You'll have to use some other mechanism, like any of the many JavaScript UI components that emulate modal dialogs.

Comment: Did this start happening with IE7? Or at some point since during a security release? Pretty annoying. :(

Comment: The first proper release of IE7 definitely had this issue.